# Etale fundamental of a parahoric group scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, fundamental-group

Let $p:X\rightarrow Y$ be a double cover of curves, denote by $$SU_n:=(p_*SL_n(\mathcal O_X))^{\tilde{\sigma}}$$
i.e. the $\tilde{\sigma}-$invariant part, the action of $\tilde{\sigma}$ is given by $$\tilde{\sigma}(g)=\,^t(g\circ\sigma)^{-1}$$ where $\sigma$ is the involution induced by the double cover. $SU_n$ is well knowing to be a parahoric group shceme in the sens of Bruhat-Tits.

My question: What is $\pi_1(({SU_n})_\eta)$ ? (the algebraic fundamental group). where $\eta$ is the generic point of $Y$.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really mean to take $g \circ \sigma$ and not $\sigma(g)$? I don't see why $\sigma$ should lie in $p_* SL_n$.

Comment: I see $g$ as an automorphism of $SL_r\times X$ and that's why I used the notation $g\circ \sigma$,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an exact sequence

$$ \pi_1 ((SU_n)_{\overline{\eta}}) \to \pi_1((SU_n)_{\eta}) \to \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\eta}|\eta)$$

Over $\overline{\eta}$, $p_* SL_n$ is just $SL_n \times SL_n$. The involution $\tilde{\sigma}$ acts by switching the two $SL_n$s and then doing an performing some automorphism, so the involution invariants $SU_n$ are just the diagonal $SL_n$ embedded by the graph of the automorphism.

In characteristic $0$, $\pi_1(SL_n)$ is trivial, so the fundamental group is just the Galois group of the base field. In characteristic $p$ things are more complicated as the fundamental group is infinite, as witnessed by the family of etale covers $g \to g^{-1} \operatorname{Frob}_q(g)$ which is Galois of group $SL_n(\mathbb F_q)$ for each $q$.

Comment: I don't see why over $\bar \eta$ the fiber shoud be two copies of $SL_r$? what is $X_{\bar\eta}$?

Comment: @Z.h $X_{\overline{\eta}}$ is just the pullback of $X$ along the map $\overline{\eta} \to X$, which is just $\overline{\eta}$ - a single point. $Y_{\overline{\eta}}$ is the pullback of $Y$ along the same map, which is two points. Thus the pushforward of $SL_r$ is two cope of $SL_r$.

Comment: I considred the 2:1 cover as $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$, so I think you mean $Y_{\bar\eta}$ is one point and $X_{\bar\eta}$ is two points? right?

Comment: @Z.h yes, precisely that.

Comment: I can't see why $X_{\bar\eta}$ is two points? because I think that the only point of $X$ whose image is the generic point of $Y$ is the generic point of $X$!!

Comment: @Z.h Yes but there are two maps from $\overline{\eta}$ to the generic point of $X$ over the generic point of $Y$, because there are two maps of function fields going the other way. A better way to think about it is that the degree of a morphism is preserved by pullback, so $X_{\overline{\eta}}$ must be a degree $2$ cover of $\overline{\eta}$, the only one of which is two points.

Comment: @Will_Sawin, thanks for your answers, but I always can't see why $X_{\bar\eta}$ is two point?!, let $K(X)$ and $K(Y)$ be the two function fields, as $K(X)$ is a quadratic extension of $K(Y)$ they have the same algebraic closure denoted $\overline{K(X)}$, now $\bar\eta$ is just the composed map $Spec(\overline{K(X)})\rightarrow Spec(K(X))$ (resp. $Spec(K(Y))$) with the map of $\eta$ $Spec(K(X))\rightarrow X$ (resp. $Spec(K(Y)\rightarrow Y$) as this two maps are unique (the first one is just induced by the inclusion $K(X)\rightarrow \overline{K(X)}$ so I see just one map on the two curves

Comment: @Z.h For the other map, use the nontrivial automorphism of $K(X)$ over $K(Y)$ and then apply the embedding into $\overline{K(X)}$. Alternately, use that $X_{\overline{\eta} } = \operatorname{Spec} K(X) \otimes_{K(Y)} \overline{K(X)} = \operatorname{Spec} \overline{K(X)} \times \overline{K(X)}$